# Is it possible to edit Entity Collections in an ASP.Net GridView that are navigation properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4, dynamic-data

First the background:  I've created an ASP.NET Dynamic Data project in VS2010.  By default, the Children.ascx file in the FieldTemplates folder displays a hyperlink when displaying children of an entity.  When you click on the link you navigate to separate webpage for the other table.  For my specific purposes, this is undesirable.  I'd like to in-line the children right in the parent page since they all collectively make up a record for my purposes.

What I did was modify the Children.ascx file and replace the Hyperlink with a GridView.  The code looks like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" 
 DataSource="<%#FieldValue%>" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
 AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
 OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated"
 HeaderStyle-CssClass="th" CellPadding="6">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        There are currently no items in this table.
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Nothing fancy, the important piece is just the "FieldValue" property that comes from the field template.  That's the entity collection being passed in.  There's nothing happening in the OnRowEditing event, it just complained when it wasn't handled so I put in a handler.

When I run the project, it displays just fine.  The child collection is rendered in the GridView just like I want.  However, when I click the "Edit" button on any row all of the columns disappear.  The rows still exist so it appears that the GridView still knows it has data, but the columns are not automatically generated (although that property isn't listed in the code above, it's set by default.)

After doing a whole bunch of reading I've found that GridViews can't bind to properties on navigation properties.  For example, if I have Table1 with a navigation property Table2, I can't bind to Table2.Column1, I'd have to use Eval.  However, I was wondering since in this case I'm feeding a whole entity collection into the GridView if that problem would be circumvented.  So that's where my question comes in.  Given my setup, is it possible to get the GridView to allow editing or am I SOL?

If this is not possible, what's a recommended way to accomplish what I'm doing (editing parent and children all on one page) in a Dynamic Data site?  I know I can drop multiple EntityDataSources on the page and just map separate GridViews for the children to those, but in my testing I've found my master table automatically loads its children.  Seems kind of a waste to create new EntityDataSources to load data that's already there.  Plus, with one EntityDataSource all the data would be automatically associated and updated in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

The parent child relationship is defined most likely in your EDMX.  Dynamic Data then uses the Children field template based on that relationship.

You need two custom controls, one for display (Children.ascx) and one for Inserting (Children_Insert.ascx).  However, I would leave those two files alone and **add** two new ones : something like ChildrenGrid.ascx and ChildrenGrid_Insert.ascx and reference these in metadata with

```
[UIHint("ChildrenGrid")]
```